# Skip Iteration Column

Tags: excel, vba

The thing I am trying to do is if `vInputs(1, i)` is less than 22 I want the code to go to the next iteration column and if it's greater than 22 to just continue with the code.

The problem is in the `If vInputs(1, i)...` line. Not sure what I am doing wrong:

```
Sub CreateTestResultTableV2()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'helps the code run faster


Dim vInputs, vResults()
Dim c As Integer, i As Integer

'create INPUTS array
c = Range("b5").End(xlToRight).Column
vInputs = Range("b5", Cells(8, c))
    'determine last value in the column
    c = UBound(vInputs, 2)

'create RESULTS array
ReDim vResults(1 To 3, 1 To c)

For i = 1 To c

    If vInputs(1, i) <= 22 Then GoTo Next i
    Else
        'set values
        Range("j16") = vInputs(1, i)
        Range("n12") = vInputs(4, i)

            'copy output values into RESULTS array
            vResults(1, i) = Range("h41")
            vResults(2, i) = Range("k41")
            vResults(3, i) = Range("z14")

Next i

Range("e47").Resize(3, c) = vResults

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: You cannot `Then Goto Next i` Next i is not a label. You cannot have a Else with an inline If.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use a `Goto` statement to skip iterations in a loop. use the opposite operator and only execute the code in the loop when the conditions are `True`.

```
For i = 1 To c

    If vInputs(1, i) > 22 Then 
        'set values
        Range("j16") = vInputs(1, i)
        Range("n12") = vInputs(4, i)

        'copy output values into RESULTS array
        vResults(1, i) = Range("h41")
        vResults(2, i) = Range("k41")
        vResults(3, i) = Range("z14")
    End if

Next i
```